# Is there any way in a SPINNER to select an item and show another value related to?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, spinner, android-spinner

I have a SQLite database with a table with "Customer" and "CustomerId" column.

Ex: Customer: John Doe
CustomerId: 84746464

I inflate spinner with data in "Customer". I need to show in spinner "84746464" when usr selects John Doe.

Is there anuway to do this in android?

Thank you!

Comment: You can change the `prompt` to show the value you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anuway to do this in android?

Yes, of cousre, here's an example that shows both the CustomerId and the Customer in the Spinner :-

This utilises a CursorAdapter which simplifies matters. However it does need a column specifically name **_id**. However, in this exmple even though the column does not exist in the table, it is generated by the query used to get All Customers (`getAllCustomers`).

The resultant Spinner when selected looks like  using the stock layout **simple_list_item_2** :-

[image]

- Note it is relatively simple to use other layouts.

The advantage with CursorAdapters *(the example uses the pretty flexible SimpleCursorAdapter)* is that they are designed to work with Cursors. Events such as **onSelectedItem** allow direct access to the source Cursor which is positioned accordingly the value of the **_id** is passed to such events *(see the code in the example for `onSelectedItem`, as this demonstrates this)*.

- As the **_id** column should be an alias of the rowid column then it will always uniquely identify the selected row *(again demonstrated in `onSelectedItem`)*.

The example includes such a listener which will both Toast a message and write a message to the log e.g. (for selecting all three in turn) :-

```
2019-12-04 07:50:30.008 7679-7679/? D/SELECTEDITEMINFO: You selected Customer >Mary CustomerID > 12345678
        The position in the List was 0
        The id passed to onItemSelected was 12345678
2019-12-04 07:50:33.828 7679-7679/a.so59159856spinner D/SELECTEDITEMINFO: You selected Customer >Agnes CustomerID > 22222222
        The position in the List was 1
        The id passed to onItemSelected was 22222222
2019-12-04 07:50:38.666 7679-7679/a.so59159856spinner D/SELECTEDITEMINFO: You selected Customer >Fred CustomerID > 84746464
        The position in the List was 2
        The id passed to onItemSelected was 84746464
```

- Note that when the Spinner is setup that the onSelectedItem will be triggered.

## The Example

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/myspinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Spinner>

</LinearLayout>
```

### DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String CUSTOMER_TABLE = "customer";
    public static final String CUSTOMER_COL_CUSTOMERID = "CustomerId";
    public static final String CUSTOMER_COL_CUSTOMER = "Customer";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + CUSTOMER_TABLE +
                        "(" +
                        CUSTOMER_COL_CUSTOMERID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                        CUSTOMER_COL_CUSTOMER + " TEXT" +
                        ")"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
    public long insertCustomer(String customerId,String customer) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(CUSTOMER_COL_CUSTOMER,customer);
        cv.put(CUSTOMER_COL_CUSTOMERID,customerId);
        return mDB.insert(CUSTOMER_TABLE,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getAllCustomers() {

        String[] columns = new String[]
                {
                CUSTOMER_COL_CUSTOMERID,
                CUSTOMER_COL_CUSTOMER,
                CUSTOMER_COL_CUSTOMERID + " AS " + BaseColumns._ID
        };
        return mDB.query(CUSTOMER_TABLE,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner mSpinner;
    DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
    Cursor mAllCustomers;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSpinnerAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSpinner = this.findViewById(R.id.myspinner);
        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        addSomeTestingCustomers();
        manageSpinner();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mAllCustomers.close(); /* Close the Cursor when done with it */
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        manageSpinner(); /* Refresh the Spinner in case data has changed */
    }

    /* Manage the Spinner */
    private void manageSpinner() {
        mAllCustomers = mDBHelper.getAllCustomers();
        if (mSpinnerAdapter == null) {
            String[] columns_to_display = new String[]{
              DatabaseHelper.CUSTOMER_COL_CUSTOMERID,
              DatabaseHelper.CUSTOMER_COL_CUSTOMER
            };
            int[] views_in_which_data_is_displayed = new int[]{
                    android.R.id.text1,
                    android.R.id.text2
            };
            mSpinnerAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    mAllCustomers,
                    columns_to_display,
                    views_in_which_data_is_displayed,
                    0);
            mSpinner.setAdapter(mSpinnerAdapter);
            mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String selected_info =
                            "You selected Customer >" +
                                    mAllCustomers.getString(mAllCustomers.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.CUSTOMER_COL_CUSTOMER)) +
                                    " CustomerID > " +
                                    mAllCustomers.getString(mAllCustomers.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.CUSTOMER_COL_CUSTOMERID)) +
                                    "\n\tThe position in the List was " + position +
                                    "\n\tThe id passed to onItemSelected was " + id
                            ;
                    Log.d("SELECTEDITEMINFO",selected_info);
                    Toast.makeText(
                            view.getContext(),
                            selected_info,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
        } else {
            /* If the Spinner has been setup then refresh the List */
            /* This would be called whenever the Database has been (or might have been) changed */
            /* typically you would override the activities onResume method to call this */
            mSpinnerAdapter.swapCursor(mAllCustomers);
        }
    }

    /* Add some testing data to the database if none already exists */
    private void addSomeTestingCustomers() {
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase(),DatabaseHelper.CUSTOMER_TABLE) < 1) {
            mDBHelper.insertCustomer("84746464","Fred");
            mDBHelper.insertCustomer("12345678","Mary");
            mDBHelper.insertCustomer("22222222","Agnes");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: The example is perfect, only one thing, I need to show only CUSTOMER ID when spinner item is selected, not both, is it possible?

If I use code above when I select an item, spinner shows CUSTOMER and CUSTOMER ID.

Comment: @user3274418 Then just use **simple_list_item_1** for the layout and **change columns_to_display** to just have the one element **DatabaseHelper.CUSTOMER_COL_CUSTOMERID** and change **views_in_which_data_is_displayed** to have the one element **android.R.id.text1**.

Comment: In this way only shows 1 value. I need to show both elements (customer, and customerid) when spinner is expanded, bun only one (customerId) when item is selected.

Comment: @user3274418 I beleiev that you would need a Custom adapter to do that. If the issue is retrieving the data the the simple get-around is to have member variables set by onItemSelected. Otherwise showing only 1 value, especially a number, when not expanded but two when expanded could be confusing to a user. But UI isn't my area.

Answer (score 0):

The example is perfect, only one thing, I need to show only CUSTOMER ID when spinner item is selected, not both, is it possible?

If I use code above when I select an item, spinner shows CUSTOMER and CUSTOMER ID.